# How can I convert OpenVino predict output to boxes?

Tags: yolo, openvino

I've deployed my YOLO model by using openvino/model_server:latest image, and I run `import numpy as np
from classes import imagenet_classes
from ovmsclient import make_grpc_client

client = make_grpc_client("localhost:9000")

with open("zebra.jpeg", "rb") as f:
img = f.read()

output = client.predict({"images": img}, "yolo")
print(output.shape)` this code, then I got (1, 84, 8400) this output. How can I use this output to draw boxes and verify which object is predict?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output tensor results, you can obtain the bounding boxes using this [YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/examples/YOLOv8-OpenCV-ONNX-Python/main.py) script which seems to load an ONNX model (which has the same output format), and convert the results into boxes with associated scores.